# how can I deploy hyperledger fabric on different physical(not virtual machine) computer (not use IBM bluemix)

Tags: blockchain

three of my computer IP is 140.116.110.xx、140.112.110.xx、140.111.110.xx
I have tried to search on Internet, but most of these are on Bluemix.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change hosts in Vagrantfile inside /fabric/devenv